# Code Optimization - Looping through Outlook subfolders to import emails into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, optimization, outlook

I have a macro which loops through 2 Outlook subfolders and imports some email information (sender, subject, date) into an Excel worksheet. There are not many emails in the subfolders (if you search across an entire month there would be maybe 100-200 emails in total). However, the macro seems to be taking an excessive amount of time to run (~3 minutes).

Any advice on getting the macro to run faster?

FYI - new to vba

```
Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub

_____

Sub OptimizeCode_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

______

Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long


Call OptimizeCode_Begin

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Individual Lot Inspections")
Set Folder2 = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Construction Site Inspections")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        ' Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body

        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

j = i + 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder2.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(j, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(j, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_sender").Offset(j, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName

        j = j + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set Folder2 = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

Call OptimizeCode_End
```

End Sub

Comment: Consider eyeballing [codereview.se]'s `/help/how-to-ask` and `/help/on-topic` pages; code reviews are typically off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, never loop through all item in a folder. Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` with a query like `[ReceivedTime] > '2018-09-01'`.

Secondly (if you do use a loop), do not continuously evaluate expressions inside the loop that never change. In your case, they are `Range("From_date").Value`, `Range("eMail_subject")`, `Range("eMail_date")`, `Range("eMail_sender")`. Evaluate these expressions before starting the loop, store the returned values in variables, and use them inside the loop.

Comment: Perfect, Items.Restrict got it running in reasonable time.